# How To Find The Table Names Which Are Locked (Specific to any transaction)

Tags: sql-server, locking, row

Is there any way to list out the locked tables and to kill the transactions if we want them to be unlocked immediately.

Or is there any other terminology do we need to follow for above operation i am seeking for.

Any Help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: There's really no need to put your subject as the first line of your question - we all read it. Also, you don't need caps, it just makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 13):

This will show all databases with exclusive locks being held (which may include transient ones held at the time this is run), using the  [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) DMV:

```
select d.*, l.* from sys.dm_tran_locks l
join sys.databases d on l.resource_database_id = d.database_id 
where l.request_mode = 'X'
```

(X = exclusive, S = Shared, IS = Intent Shared)  See [Lock Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx).

But probably the best way is to turn on Trace Flags 1204 and 1222:

> Trace Flag 1204 and Trace Flag 1222
>   When deadlocks occur, trace flag 1204
>   and trace flag 1222 return information
>   that is captured in the SQL Server
>   2005 error log. Trace flag 1204
>   reports deadlock information formatted
>   by each node involved in the deadlock.
>   Trace flag 1222 formats deadlock
>   information, first by processes and
>   then by resources. It is possible to
>   enable both trace flags to obtain two
>   representations of the same deadlock
>   event.

Ref: [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx)

Also, run `sp_who2` and look for entries in the  `BlkBy` (Blocked By) column; follow these until you get to the head of the deadlock chain. That is the process identifier (or PID) responsible.

To get what sql is running behind a specific process you can run:

```
dbcc inputbuffer (@pid)
```

and use that PID to kill the Process (with prudence and at your own risk):

```
kill @pid
```

Check out [Who is Active? v10.00: DMV Monitoring Made Easy](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2010/10/21/who-is-active-v10-00-dmv-monitoring-made-easy.aspx)

Also read [Blocking is not Deadlocking](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/07/26/Blocking-is-not-Deadlocking.aspx) (to distinguish the two scenarios)

Comment: What does BlkBy column exactly Implies is the something related to the Transaction due to which the Table has been locked. And how to kill the Process using PID. I am able to SPID column name when I execute "sp_who2"

Comment: What does the values of sys.dm_tran_locks.request_mode implies for S, IS and X as in your above Query. can you please describe this?

Comment: @K Maheshwar Rao: is this is helpful how about some upvote love?

Comment: Mitch, dbcc inputbuffer (@pid) is not displaying the complete SQL locking the table. Can you please help me how to Activate TRACE Flags 1204 and 1222 and what are the required steps we need to take ON trace flags.. And in what way it will help us. How can we see Full SQL text causing locks

Comment: gotta love putting effort into an answer, and then the OP doesn't even upvote.