# SQL Server 2008 update statement hangs

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, freeze, foreign-keys

In my SQL Server 2008 Enterprise I have a database that contains several tables:

1. `Departments` - few rows
2. `Persons` - a 300+- rows
3. `Permissions` - thousands of rows

The primary key of `Persons` is the `PersonId` combined with the `DepartmentId` (which is a FK itself).

The `Permissions` table has a FK with cascade functionality (delete, update) to the PK of the `Persons` table.

When I execute this statement:

```
UPDATE Persons SET PersonId = PersonId + 1 WHERE DepartmentId = 789
```

using SSMS, ADO, ADO.NET I either get a timeout or it takes way too long (more than 10 minutes).

I tried updating the rows one by one with ADO.NET and found out this strange behaviour: when I get to a specific rows the update starts to hang. I tried restarting, drop and create, backup and restore, deleting the rows and reinserting but haven't solved it yet.

Thanks in advance for any answers.
Hen

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have? Is the `DepartmentId` on `Persons` indexed ?? Are there other things going on in your database at the same time, e.g. could someone else be modifying or querying the `Persons` table while you try to update it??

Comment: please post the schema nad index defintions for all tables involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all instances of excessive blocking can be fixed (or at least managed) by using the appropriate indexes.

In addition, you should ensure that your indexes are rebuilt and your statistics are updated (at a minimum).

Is your clustered index defined on the composite primary key (PersonId, DepartmentId) ?

There are several ways to identify which process is blocking. One of which is `sp_who2`. Look for an entry in the `BlkBy` column.

Also see: [How To Find The Table Names Which Are Locked (Specific to any transaction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459167/how-to-find-the-table-names-which-are-locked-specific-to-any-transaction)

Answer (score 2):

If indexes have been added (manually of course, they are not automatically added with FKs) then the other major culprit is triggers firing.

Check for triggers on the tables involved.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time, but here's the identified problem:
one of the dependencies (via FK dependency) is referenced by a view, which is schema bound. The view must stay schema bound because it is being full text indexed.

The solution is dropping and recreating the view and fts index.
(Any other ideas will be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

Run sp_who2 and see what blocks are occurring if any.  If there are none consider like gdn suggested looking if you have any triggers that may be causing excessive amounts of time to finsih firing.

Answer (score -1):

Try the same query with the SQL Server Management tools just after restarting the database server. If its working fine there then you probably have some locking issues.

Try creating an Index on DepartmentId as well.

EDIT:
If its a performance problem consider creating an Index on the `Permissions` `PersonId` in addition to the Persons DepartmentId index.

Comment: "after restarting the database server" - Say what? That's not good advice!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat After restarting his database server he shouldn't have any running transactions on his server that could lock the table. Directly running the query without any application logic around it should give him a clue if he has to check what the application is doing or if its a problem with the query. Making sure that there are no other connections would be enough though.

Comment: A foreign key **does not** automatically create an index

Comment: @Udo: Restarting a server should not be done just because of held locks! It's incredibly poor advice.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat If he even has "tried restarting, drop and create, backup and restore, deleting the rows and reinserting" then he probably has his own instance.... and depending on knowledge its easier for him to restart the server instead of killing all other transcations. We usually don't restart our servers for such tests...

Comment: @MitchWheat Why don't you post us, how to check for different current users, if they cause locks and delay the execution so that the OP can solve his problem? Oh noticed, you just did. :)

Comment: Restarting SQL Server may take some time as the UPDATE probably needs rolled back on start up.